# From parametric equation to cartesian equations

Tags: differential-geometry

> Let $\alpha:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{3}$, $\;\alpha(t) = \big(t,\cosh(t),\sinh(t)\big)$. Find the cartesian equations.

I thought about the fact that $y^{2}-z^{2}= 1$, but I don't know if that can help me. I'm not very good to do this things, can you give me an advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\;x=t\;,\;y=\cosh(t)\;,\;z=\sinh(t)\;\;$ for all $\;t\in\mathbb{R}\;.$

Since $\;\cosh^2(t)-\sinh^2(t)=1\;$ for all $\;t\in\mathbb{R}\;,\;$ it follows that

$y^2-z^2=1\;.$

So the cartesian equations are the following

$\left \{ \begin{array}{rl}
y=\cosh(x)\\
y^2-z^2=1
\end{array}
\right.$